# Data structure with circular queue in c

Tags: c, arrays, queue

I've found this code that shows the operation of a circular queue.
I am experimenting with it to learn more about how queues work. 
In this case I would like to change the following implementation that instead of printing numbers it will print sentences.

I've tried changing the data type but it continues to print numbers.

Any ideas?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

#define MAX 10

void addq ( int *, int, int *, int * ) ;
int delq ( int *, int *, int * ) ;
void display ( int * ) ;

void main( )
{
    int arr[MAX] ;
    int i, front, rear ;

    system("cls" ) ;

    /* initialise data member */

    front = rear = -1 ;
    for ( i = 0 ; i < MAX ; i++ )
        arr[i] = 0 ;

    addq ( arr, 14, &front, &rear ) ;
    addq ( arr, 22, &front, &rear ) ;
    addq ( arr, 13, &front, &rear ) ;
    addq ( arr, -6, &front, &rear ) ;
    addq ( arr, 25, &front, &rear ) ;

    printf ( "\nElements in the circular queue: " ) ;
    display ( arr ) ;

    i = delq ( arr, &front, &rear ) ;
    printf ( "Item deleted: %d", i ) ;

    i = delq ( arr, &front, &rear ) ;
    printf ( "\nItem deleted: %d", i ) ;

    printf ( "\nElements in the circular queue after deletion: " ) ;
    display ( arr ) ;

    addq ( arr, 21, &front, &rear ) ;
    addq ( arr, 17, &front, &rear ) ;
    addq ( arr, 18, &front, &rear ) ;
    addq ( arr, 9, &front, &rear ) ;
    addq ( arr, 20, &front, &rear ) ;

    printf ( "Elements in the circular queue after addition: " ) ;
    display ( arr ) ;

    addq ( arr, 32, &front, &rear ) ;

    printf ( "Elements in the circular queue after addition: " ) ;
    display ( arr ) ;

    getch( ) ;
}

/* adds an element to the queue */
void addq ( int *arr, int item, int *pfront, int *prear )
{
    if ( ( *prear == MAX - 1 && *pfront == 0 ) || (  *prear + 1 == *pfront ) )
    {
        printf ( "\nQueue is full." ) ;
        return ;
    }

    if ( *prear == MAX - 1 )
        *prear = 0 ;
    else
        ( *prear )++ ;

    arr[*prear] = item ;

    if ( *pfront == -1 )
        *pfront = 0 ;
}

/* removes an element from the queue */
int delq ( int *arr, int *pfront, int *prear )
{
    int data ;

    if ( *pfront == -1 )
    {
        printf ( "\nQueue is empty." ) ;
        return NULL ;
    }

    data = arr[*pfront] ;
    arr[*pfront] = 0 ;

    if ( *pfront == *prear )
    {
        *pfront = -1 ;
        *prear = -1 ;
    }
    else
    {
        if ( *pfront == MAX - 1 )
            *pfront = 0 ;
        else
            ( *pfront )++ ;
    }
    return data ;
}

/* displays element in a queue */
void display ( int * arr )
{
    int i ;
    printf ( "\n" ) ;
    for ( i = 0 ; i < MAX ; i++ )
        printf ( "%d\t", arr[i] ) ;
    printf ( "\n" ) ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order for you to use circular queues to print sentences instead of numbers all you need to do is for the queue to be an 2D character matrix.
You can see the implementation in the code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX 10

/* adds an element to the queue */
void addq ( char **arr, char *item, int *pfront, int *prear )
{
    if ( ( *prear == MAX - 1 && *pfront == 0 ) || (  *prear + 1 == *pfront ) )
    {
        printf ( "\nQueue is full." ) ;
        return ;
    }

    if ( *prear == MAX - 1 )
        *prear = 0 ;
    else
        ( *prear )++ ;

    arr[*prear] = item ;

    if ( *pfront == -1 )
        *pfront = 0 ;
}

/* removes an element from the queue */
char * delq ( char **arr, int *pfront, int *prear )
{
    char *data ;
    char *c;
    if ( *pfront == -1 )
    {
        printf ( "\nQueue is empty." ) ;
        return NULL ;
    }

    c = (char *)malloc(50*sizeof(char));
    c = "dummy content";
    data = arr[*pfront] ;
    arr[*pfront] = c ;

    if ( *pfront == *prear )
    {
        *pfront = -1 ;
        *prear = -1 ;
    }
    else
    {
        if ( *pfront == MAX - 1 )
            *pfront = 0 ;
        else
            ( *pfront )++ ;
    }
    return data ;
}

/* displays element in a queue */
void display ( char  ** arr )
{
    int i ;
    printf ( "\n" ) ;
    for ( i = 0 ; i < MAX ; i++ )
        printf ( "%s\n", arr[i] ) ;
    printf ( "\nDone here\n" ) ;
}
void main( )
{
    char **arr = (char **)malloc(MAX * sizeof(char *));
    int i, front, rear ;
    char *ch;
    /* initialise data member */

    front = rear = -1 ;
    for ( i = 0 ; i < MAX ; i++ ) {
        arr[i] = (char *)malloc(50 * sizeof(char));
        arr[i] = "dummy content" ;
    }
    addq ( arr, "hello data 1", &front, &rear ) ;
    addq ( arr, "hello data 2", &front, &rear ) ;
    addq ( arr, "hello data 3", &front, &rear ) ;
    addq ( arr, "hello data 4", &front, &rear ) ;
    addq ( arr, "hello data 5", &front, &rear ) ;

    printf ( "\nElements in the circular queue: " ) ;
    display ( arr ) ;

    ch = delq ( arr, &front, &rear ) ;
    printf ( "Item deleted: %s", ch ) ;

    ch = delq ( arr, &front, &rear ) ;
    printf ( "\nItem deleted: %s", ch ) ;

    printf ( "\nElements in the circular queue after deletion: " ) ;
    display ( arr ) ;

    addq ( arr, "hello data 6", &front, &rear ) ;
    addq ( arr, "hello data 7", &front, &rear ) ;
    addq ( arr, "hello data 8", &front, &rear ) ;
    addq ( arr, "hello data 9", &front, &rear ) ;
    addq ( arr, "hello data 10", &front, &rear ) ;

    printf ( "Elements in the circular queue after addition: " ) ;
    display ( arr ) ;

    addq ( arr, "hello data 11", &front, &rear ) ;

    printf ( "Elements in the circular queue after addition: " ) ;
    display ( arr ) ;

}
```